# Can't install ru_core_news_md, en_core_web_md for spacy 3.0.6 through cli on apple m1

Tags: python, pip, conda, spacy

When I run in terminal `spacy` or `python -m spacy`, or `python -m spacy install ru_core_news_md` and so on I get the error:

```
30969 illegal hardware instruction  python -m spacy
```

My python version is `3.8.10`, I only get the error with spacy `3.0.6`. Previously I tried to install these models with spacy `2.3.5`, where the installation was successful through the terminal. But when I tried to load the model with `spacy.load('ru_core_news_md')`, I get the error, which informed **I haven't the model in data directory**.

I would like to use spacy `3.0.6` because I can read the documentation for all spacy's functions inside pycharm, where with `2.3.5` I couldn't. Also, it's state-of-the-art.

Comment: It sounds like you somehow got a version of spaCy for different hardware. How did you install it? Can you try uninstalling it an reinstalling it? Also note that the command is `spacy download`, not `spacy install`.

Comment: Firstly I installed spacy `3.0.6` through conda, then I dropped it to `2.3.5` through pycharm, and then I installed `3.0.6` through pip.

Comment: Looks like this might be an issue with nmslib, see here. https://github.com/allenai/scispacy/issues/372